# Where is the device tree on the Linux machine, for e.g., Debian or Ubuntu?

Tags: device-tree

These days we have device tree. I am wondering where can I see the device tree in my PC - i.e.
Debian - Release:   9.11.

When I look at the kernel config, I don't see the device tree. How come device tree isn't there in my PC.

```
vi  /boot/config-4.9.0-3-amd64
```

Answer (score 4):

x86 PCs don’t use static device trees, they use other mechanisms to enumerate installed hardware (ACPI tables, PCI enumeration, USB...). So you won’t find a corresponding `.dtb` file in `/boot`.

Comment: what do they use? I know that chrome books uses the device tree. For example, here is there recent bug - https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1135157

Comment: I think you’re reading too much into that bug as far as DT is concerned. On x86, the kernel knows about some hard-coded hardware and probes for it (*e.g.* the 8042), everything else is discovered using ACPI and bus enumeration (PCI, USB...).

Comment: Yup, as user431397 says, some x86 systems use DT. I’m answering for PCs only since that’s what you asked about.